# How to use additionProvider with repository functions?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I am trying to configure test classes for my Symfony 2.7 project. I am testing a controller that uses doctrine for connecting to the data base.

I finally managed to do it extending KernelTestCase in order to avoid this Fatal error: Call to a member function "X" on a non-object. But here is the problem: I was triying to order my code and simplify 5 test functions into one by using a additionProvider:

```
public function additionProvider()
{
    $first=$this->service->getTranslation("","en");
    return array
    (
         'original not created' =>array($first,"")
    );
}
```

and I want to use it like:

```
    /**
     * @dataProvider additionProvider
     */
    public function testGetTranslation($expected, $actual)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }
```

here is my setUp():

```
public function setUp()    
{
    self::bootKernel();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
           ->get('doctrine')
           ->getManager()
            ;
    $this->service = new \DictionaryBundle\Controller\UtilController($this->em);
 }
```

I tried to add the first test like this and the error appeared again, like if it couldn't access to the repository. So, is possible to use addittionProviders with repository functions? how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dataProvider is executed **before** the setup method. So the `service` variable is not yet initialized.

So the dataprovider method can only return *data*, you need to move the call to the service in the tested method.

[Here the paragraph of the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html):

> Note All data providers are executed before both the call to the
>   setUpBeforeClass static method and the first call to the setUp method.
>   Because of that you can't access any variables you create there from
>   within a data provider. This is required in order for PHPUnit to be
>   able to compute the total number of tests.

Comment: Now I'm doubting between leaving it splited in 5 diferent functions (one for each different flow execution) or gropping them in a single function with many asserts. What solution do you think is the cleanest?

Comment: you can continue using the dataprovider: you can pass also the arguments for instantiate your service in the tested method, the data provider return `'original not created' =>array("","en","")`and the tested method instantiate the service with the two arguments passed. Let me know if i explain what i mean. :)

Comment: Hmm do you mean return in the data provider the parameter of the service and then execute it in the testing function?

Comment: Yes, give it a try if you can

Comment: I have try it but with my data is a bit messy so I'll just leave them splited into several functions. Thanks again!